# Can't copy to network path using Filesystem.filecopy or FileSystem.CopyFile

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to copy a file from a local computer to a remote share but I get an exception saying "Can't find the specified file".

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\filename.jpg", "\\focserver2\consultoria\teste\filename.jpg")
```

The remote shared folder has full control permissions on "Everyone".

What am I doing wrong? Or it's not possible to copy to network paths using FileSystem.CopyFile ?

Thanks.

João

Comment: Are you sure that file exists in the root of the local drive C: ?

Comment: Do you have permission to the local file to `Copy`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue does not appear to be the destination but the source. I assume that the sample you showed above is NOT the real code and in the real code, you combine a couple values together to define the source. To help prevent issues, get in the habit of using the `Path.Combine()` method when concatenating strings for a file path. It's a life-saver.

The next most important thing is to learn how to debug your code by setting break-points and seeing what the values of your combined strings are before posting to websites. This is a good one to get you started.  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/debugging-tips-with-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that you are trying to access the root folder of the C:\ drive. This folder is generally locked down by the operating system, and even simple file operations don't work easily there.

Try copying the file from a subfolder e.g.

`My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\Temp\filename.jpg", "\\focserver2\consultoria\teste\filename.jpg")`